# How to completely remove a vertical or horizontal slice of an image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

#### Goal

I want to cut out a horizontal (or vertical) slice of the image so that it is fully removed and the image has reduced dimensions. I would like to do so in Photoshop CS6.

##### original

[image]

##### target

[image]

#### Approach: Snagit Editor

In Snagit Editor, there is a "Cut Out" tool that does exactly this.
[image: Screenshot of Snagit Editor's cut out tool]

#### Approach: Photoshop

I am able to do this in Photoshop CS6, but it is more cumbersome than the easiest way likely is.

1. Create one layer with the upper part of the image that I want to keep.
2. Create a second layer with the lower part of the image that I want to keep and move it up to the bottom border of the previous layer.
3. Crop the whole image to get rid of the bottom area.

This gets even more cumbersome if there are more layers that I would have to manually move around. How can I easily delete that area from all layers at once? I expect it would be as simple as in Snagit Editor if I just knew how.

Comment: It will not be as easy as snagit, its the price you pay for software being more general. But you can skip layer of upper part (or lower) only one part needs to move and then crop so its now a whopping 33% less work. You can then record this as an action.

Comment: What kind of scenario are we talking about? Like what are you making? Is it just slicing and dicing screenshots or are you perhaps designing a website or a poster or something?

Comment: @Joonas I keep stumbling over this action, for various purposes. Often I am just slicing screenshots, but sometimes I might also want to do this in a file with multiple layers

Comment: If you're designing a website or an app and you don't want to fiddle with multiple object sizes and positions after every small change, then the first app that comes to mind is Webflow, in which elements flow the same way they do in the browser: https://youtu.be/yvEsWIOz8o4?t=89 — So, in this case, you would just select the two list items in the middle, click backspace and that's it, the last item would jump up and the parent element would resize to hug the content automatically. Of course you would've had to build the list or whatever it is in Webflow... It's not a raster image editor.

Comment: Your current method does seem a bit complicated to me. Instead you could select the piece you want to move up, cut it (Ctrl+X), paste it (Ctrl+V), move it, then crop.